# ProGuard error in Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, proguard

I had made changes in `Proguard.cfg` and started getting these errors at the time of exporting app.

I'm using Google GData YouTube API. And I'm using these libraries:

```
activation.jar, additionnal.jar, crittercism_v2_1_7.jar, gdata-base-1.0.jar, gdata-client-1.0.jar, gdata-core-1.0.jar, gdata-media-1.0.jar, gdata-youtube-2.0.jar, guava-12.0.jar, GoogleAdMobAdsSdk-4.3.1.jar, mail.jar, json-simple-1.1.1.jar
```

*It is working* when I'm debugging my application on device.

Everything was working until I added below lines in `proguard.cfg`:

```
-dump proguard/class_files.txt 
-printseeds proguard/seeds.txt 
-printusage proguard/unused.txt 
-printmapping proguard/mapping.txt
```

*Errors in Ecplise console*: Please follow my pastebin link [here](http://pastebin.com/x5DLUVbp).

My *proguard.cfg* file:

```
-optimizationpasses 5
-dontusemixedcaseclassnames
-dontskipnonpubliclibraryclasses
-dontpreverify
-verbose
-optimizations !code/simplification/arithmetic,!field/*,!class/merging/*

-dump proguard/class_files.txt 
-printseeds proguard/seeds.txt 
-printusage proguard/unused.txt 
-printmapping proguard/mapping.txt 

-keep public class * extends android.app.Activity
-keep public class * extends android.app.Application
-keep public class * extends android.app.Service
-keep public class * extends android.content.BroadcastReceiver
-keep public class * extends android.content.ContentProvider
-keep public class * extends android.app.backup.BackupAgentHelper
-keep public class * extends android.preference.Preference
-keep public class com.android.vending.licensing.ILicensingService
-keep public class com.crittercism.**


-keepclasseswithmembernames class * {
    native <methods>;
}

-keepclasseswithmembers class * {
    public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet);
}

-keepclasseswithmembers class * {
    public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int);
}

-keepclassmembers class * extends android.app.Activity {
   public void *(android.view.View);
}

-keepclassmembers enum * {
    public static **[] values();
    public static ** valueOf(java.lang.String);
}

-keep class * implements android.os.Parcelable {
  public static final android.os.Parcelable$Creator *;
}

-keepclassmembers public class com.crittercism.*
{
    *;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I solved it by myself. What i did is, just add below lines in Proguard.cfg:

```
-dontwarn java.awt.**,javax.security.**,java.beans.**
-dontwarn javax.xml.stream.events.**
-dontwarn com.google.gdata.**, com.google.common.**
```

to avoid all warnings

Thankx, hope this helps someone..